# How to insert web links on the page margin?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I am typesetting a print magazine in InDesign. I would like to put URLs to related content in the margin. Ideally, I hoped I could “attach” the URL to some anchor in the main text and have the URL automatically appear in the outer margin and move with the anchor. A bit like this:

---

[image: a crude illustration]

---

Is that possible? (I know I could easily do that by hand, but I am only interested in an automatic solution that wouldn’t require me to move the URLs when the anchor moves.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use anchored objects. Which as the name suggests, are stuck — or anchored — to a specific piece of text and will follow that text as it moves.

To create an anchored object, simply place your cursor in the text where you want your object to be anchored, then go to;

> Object → Anchored Object → Insert

In the Insert Anchor Object dialog, set the content to "Text", set the paragraph style, give the object a width and height and set the positioning. If you want the object aligned to the *outer* margin, rather than the same side, check the "Relative to Spine" option. The easiest way to set the position is to set the *object's* anchor point and set an x offset relative to the text frame:

> [image]

Hit "OK" and your new anchored object will be created and active, ready for you to type in to:

> [image]

You can read more about anchored object in the Adobe help docs:

- [**Work with anchored objects in InDesign - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html)

Comment: Don't forget to tick "Relative to Spine" as well, to get them in the *outer* margin, rather than always on the same side.